# Can you add extra animations for the Compiz manager animations editor?

Tags: compiz, animations

I started playing around with the compiz manager animations bit, but they're quite boring. I wondered if there are any I can download and if so where from?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Have you already installed the extra compiz plugins? Open a terminal and enter:
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra

Comment: Yeah, not long after I posted this I did further reading and realised I didn't have the plugins. But still is there a way to download more?